# Creating a line level signal and DC power from a speaker level signal

Tags: power-supply, audio, ac-dc

I have a speaker connected to an amplifier with some wires that run through a wall. I may want to replace the regular speaker with one that has an integrated amp and takes a line level audio input and 5 V DC power micro-USB input, because it sounds better and I have it lying around anyway.

Getting a line level signal shouldn't be too hard, but it would be great if I didn't have to run an extra power cable through the wall, or try to source the power from another location in the speaker's room, and I was thinking, since the amplifier is able to provide some power to the speaker, it should be possible to extract that power on the other side and turn it into 5 V DC. Is there a circuit that can do this, while also providing the line level signal? Well, I'm pretty sure that's a yes, I could insert some resistor that would heat up and run a steam generator off it, but I'd appreciate something more practical and affordable.

I'm not at home right now so can't provide more specs, but I'm assuming that the amplifier can provide enough power for continuous operation of the speaker at the required volume. However, as an extra complication, the speaker (a JBL Charge 3) has a battery, and when charging it will probably try to draw more power than the average consumption of continuous operation. Per the USB spec, I believe it may try to draw up to 1.5 A (if the USB data lines are shorted), while automatically reducing that if it detects the supply voltage browning out. So it would be great to have the converter brown out before it fries the amplifier, in case the latter is not capable of supplying that 7.5 W. Oh and I guess it should turn itself off completely if the available power is less than the USB minimum of 0.5 W, e.g. during quiet parts.

By the way, the intent of this question is to change (nearly) nothing on the amplifier side. That is, while simply injecting a DC offset on that side and extracting it on the other side is probably a more practical solution, I'm also just curious whether it *could* be done as described (no XY problem here).

The signal is mono, but a solution supporting stereo gets bonus points. Likewise, I'm assuming the amplifier can drive the line at an RMS voltage > 5 V, but bonus points for a solution that can work if the amp is low-voltage, high-current (although it's probably just a matter of adding a boost converter).

Comment: No transformers allowed?

Comment: @jonk anything is allowed as long as it's practical. Actually, even impractical solutions would be interesting and educational to read.

Comment: Thinking out loud: the power extractor should act as a constant resistance load in order to maintain signal integrity, but that would give it a variable power consumption as audio volume changes. Yet, it should probably provide a somewhat constant power output...

Comment: My first instinct was to use a transformer that provides a "speaker load" to your driver, replacing the speaker that way, and where the secondary is designed to match up with the needs for the line output. You have way more power than you need, so passives can be used to attenuate, as needed, I'd imagine. But I gather you don't just want a line level audio. You want a 5 V DC supply that can be elsewhere used, right? (It's not enough to just get a line level output without making a DC supply.)

Comment: @jonk yes, the 5 V DC requirement is what sets this apart from other, similar questions. It is however not used "elsewhere" but to power the internal amplifier of the speaker+amp unit, so there is still a relation between the audio signal and power draw. And yes, adding power to line level to make it speaker level, then reversing that, only to do have the speaker put them back together again does seem very redundant (just use a better regular speaker with the speaker level signal!), and the only reason to do it is because the speaker+amp is a sunk cost.

Comment: Well, harvesting a usable 8 W, given efficiencies, means at least 10 W and if the power recovery circuitry is not switcher-based then probably worse than that. Music is often running at 15-20% of the maximum power of an amp (or less) as peaks need to be handled well and that requires a lot of reserve. Also, there will be silence at times and you may need battery to bridge those. Only you know enough details and I think we need a lot more from you than we have in hand. Details only you know right now. And designing for all circumstances, not just you, would make this even harder to consider.

Comment: And all that was just random guessing. I am pretty sure that saying 10 W to get 8 W out is a total guess and I don't think it would be readily achievable from sound variations, even with switchers involved (and relatively sophisticated ones, at that.) The 15-20% figure is not too far from truth, though. And that's when playing loud. Luckily, my hearing is going. So when I need sound, my family says they can hear it from the moon-bounce (through the vacuum of space!) Might work for me. That much power. But you? Anyway. Too much to think over for me, I think.